# lock camera using services and broadcast receiver

Tags: android, service, android-camera

my application running services and lock camera to take pictures or videos but after some time camera will unlock automatically . tried to use alarm manager but its not working with camera lock feature.  given error that fail to open camera services.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think its a bad idea to permanently lock camera in your service because in that case your camera will not available for any other application. Now tell me one thing you are opening your camera in your activity or in your service. And where you are releasing your camera.

Comment: my objective is to lock camera for particular time period when my app is running in users device.open  and lock camera in service and not releasing camera.dont know where to release camera in services.

Comment: Ok you know when you want to take photo..

Comment: where to release camera?

Comment: If you are not using intent then you will open camera somewhere or and display preview on surfaceview or any other surface while destroy that surface you can release camera or you can show some code i will try to help you..

Comment: public class ServiceTemplate extends Service
{
 Camera _camera;
    MediaRecorder mRecorder;
   
 public void startRecording() throws IllegalStateException
 {
 
   _camera=Camera.open();_camera.lock();
  }
 
 @Override
 public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
 {
  return null;
 }

Comment: There is no surface how you will take picture. Can you explain me... I don't think it will ever take picture or you are taking picture.

Comment: i dont want to take picture what i want is when user trying to use camera my app will stop them to use any camera functions for security of business data theft

Comment: ok at the beginning your camera is opening properly. If yes then I think your camera is open but not locked. so you need to lock it again. use if (mCamera != null) {mCamera.lock();}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok at the beginning your camera is opening properly. If yes then I think your camera is open but not locked. so you need to lock it again. whenever you want to lock it again.

```
if (mCamera != null)
{
      mCamera.lock();
}
```

if you want to reopen your camera then use this in your alarm manager it will not give you runtime error. Or you can only lock your camera again. this process you can repeat in 10 or 15 minutes.

```
if (mCamera != null) {
      mCamera.release();
      mCamera = null;
}
mCamera = Camera.open();
```

Comment: camera lock is working but after some time ( i.e. 25 mins) automatically camera unlock function working and when check services it display service is running.